# Underscore / Backbone templating with Django

Tags: javascript, django, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

when defining my javascript templates within

```
<script type="text/template">
</script>
```

they don't get rendered in html (i don't see them in the page, I mean) in my Django application. Maybe one of the filters / middlewares I've declared is opting them out?

This is from `settings.py`

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
if DEBUG:
    COMPRESS_REBUILD_TIMEOUT = 1

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     "django.core.context_processors.request",
     "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
     "django.core.context_processors.debug",
     "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
     "django.core.context_processors.media",
     "django.core.context_processors.static",
     "django.core.context_processors.tz",
     "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

If so, how to solve this?

**EDIT**
The template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="new-catalog-template">

    <div class="catalog" data-id="<%= responseJSON.catalog.id %>" style="display: none">
        <div class="catalog-main-content">
            <div class="preview"><img src="<%= responseJSON.user_dir %>/catalogs/<%= responseJSON.catalog.id %>/ipad-preview-icon-large.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="name"><%= responseJSON.catalog.name %></div>
            <div class="last-build"><em>Last build:</em><%= responseJSON.catalog.last_build_natural %> (<%= responseJSON.catalog.last_build %>)</div>
            <div class="description"><%= responseJSON.catalog.description %></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</script>
```

** EDIT EDIT **

My bad, the script tag was outside the main block and hence not rendered ¬_¬ ... Thanks for letting me know about `{{ verbatim }}`, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could I please see that template?

If not - maybe you could use the [escapejs-Filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escapejs) or better the new [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#verbatim) tag.